# C# & XAML - Display JSON in ListView from Wunderground API

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, wunderground

I am new to C# and XAML and am working on a simple Weather App that lets you search for city and state and returns a formatted 10-day forecast list.

I'm having problems displaying data retrieved from the [Wunderground Weather API](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/forecast10day) using a ListView. This is the JSON I'm working with, [example.](http://api.wunderground.com/api/28af05d873029695/forecast10day/q/CA/San_Francisco.json)

**My problem**:
How do I run all List items through a template in XAML that displays the items properties' (icon_url, title, fcttext) after we get the results from the Wunderground API?

Here is my model:

```
    public class ForecastList
        {
            public class Forecastday
            {
                public string icon_url { get; set; }
                public string title { get; set; }
                public string fcttext { get; set; }
            }

            public class TxtForecast
            {
                public List forecastday { get; set; }
            }

            public class Forecast
            {
                public TxtForecast txt_forecast { get; set; }
            }

            public class RootObject
            {
                public Forecast forecast { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

XAML:

`<Stack Layout Padding="30">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="City" x:Name="City" />
        <Entry Placeholder="2 letter state" x:Name="State" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Button Text="Search" Clicked="OnClicked" />
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding FctText}" />
            <Image Source="{Binding IconUrl}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
    </StackLayout>`

And the ViewModel:

```
    public class MainPageViewModel
        {
            public async Task GetWeatherAsync(string url)
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

                var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonResult);
                SetList(weather);
            }

            public List ListSource { get; set; }

            private string _title;
            public string Title 
            { 
                get 
                { 
                    return _title; 
                } 
                set 
                { 
                    _title = value; 
                } 
            }

            private string _fctText;
            public string FctText 
            { 
                get
                {
                    return _fctText;
                }
                set
                {
                    _fctText = value;
                }
            }

            private string _iconUrl;
            public string IconUrl
            {
                get
                {
                    return _iconUrl;
                }
                set
                {
                    _iconUrl = value;
                }
            }

            private void SetList(ForecastList.RootObject weather)
            {
                ListView listView = new ListView();
                var forecastList = weather.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday;
                List listSource = new List(forecastList);

                ListSource = listSource;

                listView.ItemsSource = ListSource;
            }
        }
```

Cheers!

Comment: Generally, I would suggest Newton Soft JSON Library if you are working with .NET and JSON. 

The main task is the binding from the list to the JSON result. I would recommend creating a "list of" with your class and bind this list to the XAML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert server data to normal form using Dto's

for example :

This is my Dto

```
public class SampleDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Getting data from server like this

```
public static async Task<T> GetResultFromApi<T>(string serviceUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            GetConnection();
             var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(yourUrl + serviceUrl));

            var stringAsync = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseJson = stringAsync;

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseJson);
            }

            LoggingManager.Error("Received error response: " + stringAsync);
            return default(T);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LoggingManager.Error(exception);
            return default(T);
        }
    }

var gettingDto = await GetResultFromApi<SampleDto>(string.Format(client.BaseAddress));
```

and finally converting myDto to original format that i want to

```
var entity = ConvertGameDtoToEntity(gettingDto);

public SampleEntity ConvertGameDtoToEntity(SampleDto gettingDto)
{
        return new SampleEntity 
        {
            Id = gettingDto.Id,
            Name= gettingDto.Name,
            Address = gettingDto.Address,
        };
}
```

below link with clear description
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36781/Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET-with